Can I securely use confidential client auth in an iOS app if I have a server?
I’m trying to understand if I can do what I would like to accomplish with Oauth without creating security issues.
I have an iOS app that connects to a 3rd party oauth api currently using PKCE auth. It stores the refresh/access tokens in the keychain and as soon as a refresh happens the old refresh token gets invalidated and the new one gets stored instead. Refresh token rotation only happens for pkce auth, not for standard confidential client auth.
I want to add some serverside capabilities with user accounts for users that opt into a certain feature, where the server would also need to have an active session for that user.
My current setup will not work with this because the 3rd party API invalidates the refresh token once renewed, so that means that the app and server side can’t maintain active sessions.
So I am wondering if there is a that I can securely switch my usage in my app to client credential flow and maybe have a server that steps in the middle and has the client secrets in it, so the app could use client credential flow and then send a refresh token into the server for certain users and the server can have an active session.
is this possible?

Usually an API shouldn't use the refresh token and instead only receives an access token. So the simplest option is perhaps just to do this:

iOS app sends access token to API
API returns 401 when the access token expires
iOS app tries to refresh the access token and, on success, calls the API with a new access token

You iOS app delivers the user identity securely, in an access token, which the API can verify. You shouldn't use the client credentials flow for user level operations.
Or does the 3rd party API require a different type of access token? Usually each organization issues their own tokens to protect their data. Is there more than one flow involved? If so maybe update your question and I may be able to improve on my answer.
